# found wifi problem in Ubuntu in VMware

Tags: wireless, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu in VMware. I can't find the my wifi network and only can connect to internet by Ethernet.

[image]

Comment: Is it a PCI(e) wifi card?  If it is the vmware will need to support PCI passthrough and that isn't an issue with Ubuntu

Comment: This is probably not an Ubuntu issue. VMWare virtualizes hardware, including the network. For simplicity it's presented to guest as ethernet, but host connectivity can be more or less anything. Why do you need wifi in the VM?